# How can I prove that $1 + 2 + \cdots + x = \{P : P = \text{Perfect Number}\} \Leftrightarrow 2^n - 1 = x = \{M_p : n\in \mathbb{N}\}?$

Tags: prime-numbers, mersenne-numbers

I looked at formulas concerning prime numbers, and I came across *Mersenne Primes* which are primes of the form $2^n - 1 : n\in \mathbb{N}$ and the symbol used to denote a mersenne prime is $M_p$.

Along with mersenne primes, I came across the formula: $$(2^n - 1)(2^{n - 1}) = \{P : n \in \mathbb{N}, \ 2^n - 1 = M_p \ \land \ P =\text{Perfect Number}\}$$ but I also found out something else which I *didn't* come across, and I don't want to say that I discovered it because I am sure someone else must have discovered it: $$1 + 2 +\cdots+x = P \iff 2^n - 1 = x = \{M_p : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$$
For example; $$1 + 2 + 3 = 6 \implies 6\text{ is a perfect number}\because 2^2 - 1 = 3 = \text{Mersenne Prime}$$
$$1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28 \implies 28\text{ is perfect}\because 2^3 - 1 = 7 = \text{Mersenne Prime}$$
However, every time I try to research something like this, this symbol is always related to it $\longrightarrow \sum$ but I do not know what it means, so I have made an attempt of trying to see if it works.

---

**My Attempt:**
$$\begin{align} P &= 1 + 2 + \cdots + x \\ &= 1 + 2 + \cdots + 2^n - 1 \\ &= 2 + \cdots + 2^n \\ &= 2(2^{n - 1} + 1) + \cdots \end{align}$$
I can actually get every even number in the sum and put it in the bracket, and every odd number and put that outside the bracket:
$$\implies 2(2^{n - 1} + 1 + 2 + \cdots + x_1) + 3 + 5 + \cdots + x_2 = P : x_1 \in \mathbb{N} \ \land \ \color\purple{x_2 \in \mathbb{N}_{2n - 1, \ \forall n \in \mathbb{N}}}$$.
$$\because \overbrace{o_1 + o_2 + \cdots + o_n}^{\text{$n$ times}} = n^2 : o_n = \text{$n^{th}$ odd number}$$
$$\begin{align} \implies 2(2^{n - 1} + 1 + 2 + \cdots + x_1) + (x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1) &= P \because o_1 = 1 \\ \implies 2(2^{n - 1} + 1 + 2 + \cdots + x_1) &= P - (x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1) \\ &= P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} + 1 \\ \implies 2^{n - 1} + 1 + 2 + \cdots + x_1 &= \frac{P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} + 1}{2} \\ &= \frac{P}{2} - \frac{x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}}}{2} + \frac{1}{2} \\ \implies 2^{n - 1} + \frac{1}{2} + 2 + 3 + \cdots + x_1 &= \frac{P}{2} - \frac{x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}}}{2} \\ \implies \frac{2^n + 1}{2} + 2 + 3 + \cdots + x_1 &= \frac{P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}}}{2} \\ \implies 2^n + 1 + 4 + 6 + \cdots + 2x_1 &= P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} \\ \implies 2^n + 1 + 2(2 + 4 + \cdots + x_1) &= P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} \\ \implies 2(2^{n - 1} + 2 + 4 + \cdots + x_1) + 1 &= P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} \\ \implies 2^{n - 1} + 2 + 4 + \cdots + x_1 &= \frac{P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1}{2} \\ \implies 2(2^{n - 2} + 1 + 2 + \cdots + x_1) &= \frac{P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1}{2} \\ \implies 2(2^{n - 2} + P) &= \frac{P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1 }{2} \\ \implies 2^n + P &= P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1 \\ \therefore P &= P - x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} - 1 - 2^n \\ &= P - (x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} + 1 + 2^n) \\ \therefore \color\red{x_2^{\text{ $ \ 2$}} + 1 + 2^n} &\color\red{=} \color\red{0} \end{align}$$
Could you please explain to me where I made a mistake? I must have made it somewhere because the last equation highlighted in red doesn't make any sense! Surely this must be a contradiction unless their is a mistake. Any help would be appreciated, but I would mostly appreciate if you reveal the meaning of this symbol $\longrightarrow \sum$. I am in Year 9, so I may not be ready to know what it means... It looks Greek to me, but I don't know what letter it is in the Greek alphabet.

Also, did I write the part highlighted in purple correctly?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It's a capital Sigma. It is a short notation for a Sum, and is sometimes also referred to as "summation-symbol" ( see wiki)

Comment: Well, the sum of the $n$ first natural numbers is $n(n+1)/2$. These numbers are called triangular numbers (google it to know why). What you have found is that even perfect numbers are triangular. Euler proved that even perfect numbers are of the form $P(P+1)/2$ where $P$ is a Mersenne prime. Thus, an even perfect number is the $P$-th triangular number for some Mersenne prime $P$. But... if you don't know what $\sum$ means, you have done an outstanding job for your math knowledge!

Comment: @ajotatxe thank you. I do a lot of maths in my spare time because I love it and enjoy it (aka I am a nerd, and I also like science). I now understand what the following means: $$\sum_{k = 1}^{\sqrt{2^{n - 1}}}(2k - 1)^3 = P \iff (2^n - 1)(2^{n - 1}) = P$$